# 'document.getElementById().value' makes my code stop working

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have and html output from googlw web app. The problem is my code does not work when I try to use `var value = document.getElementById('reason').value();`

Otherwise it works fine. I am unable to understand why it is not able to get the value and why code stops working.

I read similar online problems but unable to find the solution.

My Html Code looks like this:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="center" style="color:white">Welcome to Comet 0.1</h1>
    <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=dash" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" style="visibility:hidden" id="dash"><i class="material-icons right">web</i>DashBoard</a>
    <div class="row"></div>

    <a id="attendance_button" onclick="setStatus()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large"><i class="material-icons right">today</i>Log in</a>

    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
    <select class="browser-default" id="reason">
    <option value="x" disabled selected>If Reported Late, Select Your Reason Then Click Log Out</option>
    <option value="Cab was late">Cab was late</option>
    <option value="Cab did not report for my pickup">Cab did not report for my pickup</option>
    <option value="Due to Personal Reason">Due to Personal Reason</option>
    <option value="On Half Day">On Half Day</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

  <p style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif; font-size: 62px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 72px; margin: 0 0 24px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase" id="demo"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script> 
    function setStatus() {

    block();
    var value = document.getElementById('reason').value();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setButtonName).changeStatus(value);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You have a space in front of reason ‘ reason’. Correct the typo. 
Have you checked the console for error? If not, it is always a good idea to check first when is codes stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value()` doesn't exist on `select` element. It's `.value` So do the following:-

```
var value = document.getElementById('reason').value;
```

Comment: That's correct working with serverside javascript made me do so lol. Thank's a lot